# Does the Qur'an contain an ayah about passing on knowledge being like a seed to be planted?

Tags: quran, source-identification

Some time ago, I heard a quote that someone said came from the Qur'an. I have not been able to find it, and I would like to know if it is a real quote. It went something like this: "If a person gains knowledge and does not pass it on, then the knowledge is like a seed that is not planted". I'm not sure if that is exactly right, I am sorry if I am misquoting the Qur'an. Does anybody recognize this?

Comment: Closest ayah I can think of is [Al-Baqarah 261](http://legacy.quran.com/2/261) but that's about *wealth* rather than *knowledge*.

Comment: It seems to me that here a mix between two different verses happened.